# Accorian menu is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using accordin menu in my site, placed in Master Page, 
It has 4 pane, each pane have multiple links.

it was working fine previously. But suddenly it is displaying this error message

> There is no source code available for
>   the current location.

It's is asking for show assembly. When I clicked on that I got a stopage at the stack
0000001a  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]

-- I am really not sure what does it means.

Also, there are several links in accordin menu, after clicking on anyone of the link I am not able to click the other link, might be because of the above reason.

Please help

Comment: That's not an error message, that's a debugger message. What's the actual error message?

Comment: Do you mean "accordian" menu? What product are you using?

Comment: @Arronaught. hahahaha I'm awesome. I +1 your comment at my own expense.

Comment: Yes ! I am not getting any error message, but this debugger message.
After this message only third pane of accordion is not working properly.
But when I pasted the same code into another aspx page, it is working fine. 
I am unable to guess the reason :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this !

Just made cause validation = false to every link inside accordion menu and it is now working fine. I don't know how this has happened but I am posting this if any one else is facing the same issue, he/she could do the same, might be it work's for them.

Thanks to all :)